# SQL Query replace UNION ALL with JOINS or something

Tags: sql, union

Now I have 3 tables

Orders:

> ID | Date | Machine | Planning

GoodPieces:

> ID | Date | Machine | Pieces | Product

BadPieces:

> ID | Date | Machine | Pieces | Product | Component

The output of the query is

> Date | Machine | Planning | GoodPieces | BadPieces

The actual query is something like that:

```
SELECT
  data.Date AS Date,
  data.Machine AS Machine,
  SUM(CASE WHEN data.type = 'Planning' THEN data.value END ) AS Planning,
  SUM(CASE WHEN data.type = 'GoodPieces' THEN data.value END ) AS GoodPieces,
  SUM(CASE WHEN data.type = 'BadPieces' THEN data.value END ) AS BadPieces
FROM
      ( SELECT
          'Planning' AS Type,
          Date AS Date,
          Machine AS Machine,
          Planning AS Value
        FROM Orders
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          'GoodPieces',
          Date,
          Machine,
          Pieces AS Value
        FROM GoodPieces
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          'BadPieces'
          Date,
          Machine,
          Pieces AS Value
        FROM BadPieces ) AS data
GROUP BY
   Date,
   Machine
```

My question is if is there a way to get the same output with this 3 tables

Orders:

> ID | Date | Machine| Planning

GoodPieces:

> OrderID | Pieces | Product

BadPieces:

> OrderID | Pieces | Product | Component

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just `LEFT JOIN` in the tables and sum the appropriate columns:

```
SELECT
  O.Date,
  O.Machine,
  SUM(COALESCE(O.Planning, 0)) AS Planning,
  SUM(COALESCE(G.Pieces, 0)) AS GoodPieces,
  SUM(COALESCE(B.Pieces, 0)) AS BadPieces
FROM
  Orders O
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT G.OrderID,
     SUM(COALESCE(G.Pieces, 0)) AS GoodPieces
   FROM GoodPieces G
   GROUP BY G.OrderID) G ON G.OrderID = O.ID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT B.OrderID,
     SUM(COALESCE(B.Pieces, 0)) AS BadPieces
   FROM BadPieces B
   GROUP BY B.OrderID) B ON B.OrderID = O.ID
GROUP BY
  O.Date,
  O.Machine;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09a73/17

**Edit**: Updated to handle point given by `@MikaelEriksson` in comments.

Comment: This will work if `OrderID` is unique in `BadPieces`. Try to add (8, 1) to `BadPieces`. The calculation for `BothTest` will be wrong.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Excellent point!  I have updated by summing together data in `GoodPieces` and `BadPieces` by `OrderID` in subqueries.  Now the data matches even with your case added, tested original query here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1698e/3

Comment: SQL FIDDLE i didn't know that page.. Thank you so match.. and Thanks for the solution

Comment: One more thing... I see the Execution plan in SQL Fiddle and looks like the UNION ALL Qry is better... Is that true?

Comment: They look about the same to me.  Both involve table scans for all three tables and a ~50% cost sort operation.  If you desire, you could implement this in your `UNION ALL` method as well by joining the Orders data into each subquery: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09a73/21

Comment: thanks for the options.. very precise answers and sorry for my english :P